# Is there a way to prevent UILabel from type checking as UIView?

Tags: swift, typechecking

In my application I'm using the `as` operator to check what type of UI element I'm working with. I ran into an issue where UILabel is successfully checking as a view.

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "some text"

if let myLabel = label as? UIView {
    print("its a view ") // succeeds
}
```

I also receive the warning that states:

> warning: Conditional cast from 'UILabel' to 'UIView' always succeeds.

### Question

Is there a way to add a constraint to this `as` check that will cause this check to fail as expected?

Comment: This seems more like a problem in your logic. Why do you even test that a label is a view?

Comment: @Sulhan, or perhaps that's not the way my program actually works, rather a succinct illustration of the problem?

Comment: I feel that problems like this (where you end up checking the type of your objects) usually have a solution based on architecture improvement, not a particular language syntax.

Comment: @Sulthan I'm using the fascade pattern to apply styles to my labels, buttons and views. This is just an experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if label.isMemberOfClass(UIView.self) {
    print("its a view ") // succeeds
}
```

`isMemberOfClass` checks for `UIView` and no classes that inherit from it

Comment: Very nice, I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Thanks! I updated it to remove the `if let` since there is no need to unwrap

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, which is the one I needed for my particular situation as I was attempting to check a generic (`T`). Since I didn't specify that in the question, I'll won't accept this as the answer, but here is the solution:

```
if let label = obj as? UILabel where label.isMemberOfClass(UILabel.self) {
    // ...
}

if let view = obj as? UIView where view.isMemberOfClass(UIView.self) {
    // ...
}
```